# Difference among sleep() and usleep() in PHP

Tags: php, sleep, usleep

Can any body explain me what is the difference among `sleep()` and `usleep()` in PHP.

I have directed to use following scripts to do chat application for long pulling but in this script I am getting same effect using `usleep(25000);` or without `usleep(25000);`

**page1.php**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" 
       type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var lpOnComplete = function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    // do more processing
    lpStart();
};

var lpStart = function() {
    $.post('page2.php', {}, lpOnComplete, 'json');
};

$(document).ready(lpStart);
</script>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
$time = time();
while((time() - $time) < 30) {
    // query memcache, database, etc. for new data
    $data = getLatest();

    // if we have new data return it
    if(!empty($data)) {
        echo json_encode($data);
        break;
    }

    usleep(25000);
}

function getLatest() {
    sleep(2);
    return "Test Data"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: sleep() takes a number of seconds as its parameter and usleep() takes a number of microseconds - millionths of a second as its parameter.

Comment: http://wordpressapi.com/how-to-use-sleep-usleep-function-in-php/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The argument to `sleep` is seconds, the argument to `usleep` is microseconds. Other than that, I think they're identical.

```
sleep($n) == usleep($n * 1000000)
```

`usleep(25000)` only sleeps for 0.025 seconds.

Comment: Another important difference is that usleep uses CPU cycles, sleep does not.

Comment: @EllertvanKoperen Wouldn't that depend on whether the OS provides a built-in way to do sub-second sleeps?

Comment: That, and wether you use some big chunks or many small chunks of sleepytime.

Comment: If there's a performance difference, it's almost certainly negligible and not worth updating the answer over.

Answer (score 6):

`sleep()` allows your code to sleep in seconds.

- `sleep(5); // sleeps for 5 seconds`

`usleep()` allows your code with respect to microseconds.

- `usleep(2500000); // sleeps for 2.5 seconds`

Answer (score 2):

`usleep()` is used to delay execution in "microseconds" while `sleep()` is used to delay execution in seconds.
So `usleep(25000)` is 0.025 seconds.

```
Is there any difference between the two?
```

Answer (score 2):

One other difference is sleep returns 0 on success, false on error. usleep doesn't return anything.

Comment: you can just mention it in a comment in the accepted answer

Comment: @Grzegorz Actually, I can't because I need 50 rep to comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Simply**

> `usleep` uses `CPU Cycles` while `sleep` does not.

`sleep` takes `seconds` as argument

while `usleep` takes `microseconds` as argument